# Trying to include html file in another html file, gives CORS error

Tags: html

Am getting this error, What is this this and how can I resolve this.

> Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'file:///C:/Users/xyz/Desktop/asdf/abcd.html' from origin 'null' has been blocked by CORS policy: Cross origin requests are only supported for protocol schemes: http, data, chrome, chrome-extension, https.

Answer (score 1):

I was facing the same problem and tried several methods for it including changing the browser but nothing worked. Finally i found out the solution to it.
You need to create a local server to run it.

Install Node.Js Open cmd and write the command

```
npm i -g live-server
```

Change path to the folder in which your html files are, and run:

```
live-server
```

It should launch your html page from entry point.

Comment: This answer helped me solve my problem. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

if you added cross origin extension to your chrome,then try to disable the cross origin extension from your chrome browser then you can make requests.It will stop the requests if the origin is mismatch. it will only allow the requests from same origin.To know more about check with this
https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/xhr